# Page content is missing after plugin activated (WPML)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

I'm using WPML with WooCommerce to do some translations,
the pages are fine, but when I activate the plugin all the pages content disappear (default language) except the homepage.

I have tried troubleshooting, update WooCommerce Multilingual, deactivate other plugins and many solutions, but nothing worked.

any help, please?

Comment: Please provide code snippets or configuration examples that you have tried or is not working. The question looks too broad.

Comment: @prasun i have tried all this steps : https://wpml.org/faq/content-is-missing-after-install/   http://wpml.org/documentation/support/debugging-wpml/    and  https://wpml.org/forums/topic/posts-and-pages-disappeared/  and https://wpml.org/forums/topic/pages-disappearing-upon-activation-of-plugin/   but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

When missing content/pages/posts after installing WPML related plugins. The best solution is:

- Back up your site
- Activate the WPML plugins
- Deactivate all non WPML related plugins
- Switch to a default WP theme
- Go to WPML > Support > Troubleshooting and perform all the actions of the "Clean up" section
- Your content should be back now
- Switch back to your theme

Maybe a little late for you. But i hope it helps others in the future.

Source: https://wpml.org/forums/topic/hi-i-just-installed-wpml-and-simply-cant-see-the-pages-im-trying-to-create/